# How can i add ActionBar in Material Design?

Tags: android

I am troubling to view an Action bar in my application?

I can view Toolbar into my Firstpage but i can not show in Second Page.

I have getting some error...

Here is my java code

```
public class ContentPage extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_page);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

   setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

}

& here is my error what i see...

```
12-22 16:34:22.022 12457-12457/nextappsbd.testapplicationforhamza E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: nextappsbd.testapplicationforhamza, PID: 12457
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nextappsbd.testapplicationforhamza/nextappsbd.testapplicationforhamza.ContentPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5344)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                                                    at nextappsbd.testapplicationforhamza.ContentPage.onCreate(ContentPage.java:28)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5361)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5344) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my MainActivity..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

}

I show the toolbar in MainActivity but i can not show this toolbar in ContentPage Activity.

How can i solve this??

Comment: why using `ActionBarActivity` ? It's a deprecated . Use `AppcompatActivity`

Comment: which Activity i Can USE?

Comment: I am getting Error  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);  in those line when i use only Activity

Comment: use AppCompartActivty and if you are useing android studio then create new project with toolbar its add full code with sample. because actionbar is depricated in API 23 listed of that use toolBar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I do this but there is same error show..

Comment: this is not a Duplicate Question @Amy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version ***22.1.0***, the class **[ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)** is deprecated. You should use **[AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)**.

```
public class ContentPage extends AppCompatActivity
```

Then

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_page);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

You can also go through this [example](http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/)